# How to add html glyph markup to JQuery show/hide function

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a very basic show/hide function that slides a sticky header up and down to reveal more contents. I've managed to get the trigger to change the text to the appropriate wording when the container is opened or closed but Id like to also add an up arrow and down arrow glyph to the appended text as well. How can this be achieved?

> The output that I'm looking for should look something like this:
>   ↓ Expand Playlist
>  ↑ Close Playist

Below is what my markup looks like thus far:

**HTML**

```
<div id="sticky_header">
    <div id="sticky_content" class="player">
        <a href="#" id="toggle_sticky_header">Expand Playlist</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/* 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sticky Header
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

#sticky_header {
    background-color: #000000;
    /* border-bottom: 5px solid #B54000; */
    border-bottom: 5px solid #0995B0;
    /* height: 100px; */
    height: 600px;
    min-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: -500px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 2000;

    box-shadow: 0px 1px 15px #000000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 15px #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 15px #000000;
}

#sticky_content {
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 990px;
    padding: 15px 0px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    position: relative;
}

a#toggle_sticky_header {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -560px;
    right: 0px;
    color: #0995B0;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
<!-- Toggle sticky header -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#toggle_sticky_header').click(function(){
        if($("#sticky_header").css("top") == "-500px") {
          $("#sticky_header").animate({top: "0px"}, 500);
        } else {
          $("#sticky_header").animate({top: "-500px"}, 500);
        }

        $(this).toggleClass("active"); 

        if ($(this).html() == "Expand Playlist") {
            $(this).html("Close Playlist");
        }
        else if ($(this).html() == "Close Playlist") {
            $(this).html("Expand Playlist");
        }

        return false;
    });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you're using `html()`, you could simply use the html entity:

```
if ($(this).html() == "Expand Playlist") {
    $(this).html("&uarr; Close Playlist");
}
else if ($(this).html() == "Close Playlist") {
    $(this).html("&darr; Expand Playlist");
}
```

Though I'd suggest a slight amendment:

```
$(this).html(function(i,h){
    return h == '&darr; Expand Playlist' ? '&darr; Expand Playlist' : '&uarr; Expand Playlist'
});
```

References:

- [HTML Symbol Entities](http://www.webstandards.org/learn/reference/charts/entities/symbol_entities/).

Comment: Strange, I previously tried using the HTML entity and nothing happened. Ill give your other suggestion a try and see how that goes instead.

Comment: Using your first suggestion, I realize that I was adding the HTML entity to the wrong part of the string, but even after trying that example what happens is the text never changes to "Close Playlist" after doing so and stays that way... I tried your other amendment and that seems much cleaner. Thank you.